# sort by association field in sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

In my app I am using Sunspot for a fulltext search. The problem is that I want to have sorting by association model field. In my case:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :genre, :name
  has_many :premieres
end
```

and my `Premier` model has:

```
belongs_to :movie
```

Searching by movie name is done by defining the method:

```
def movie_name
  movie.name
end
```

but when I try to do:

```
order_by :movie_name, :asc
```

It says:

> No field configured for Premiere with name 'movie_name'

How do I make this sorting available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
searchable auto_index: true do
  text :movie_name do
    if self.movie.present?
      self.movie.name
    end
  end
end
```

then you can use

```
order_by :movie_name, :asc
```